# If Profile2 fields are empty, problem in accessing data

Tags: 7, theming, users

I just found out that if ALL fields of certain *Profile2* profile ie. main are empty, I am not able to access data inside main profile. For example I want to do a check if a field is empty but can not access it using

```
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
$data = profile2_load_by_user($account);
```

How can I access the fields? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that profiles only get created when needed, hence when it is saved with field values.

You most probably then are trying to look at a profile of a user who does not yet have a profile. You should do a test on $data. If it is null or false, then you should assume that the user has no profile and that the fields are in effect empty. If you want to alter the fields then you must set up a profile object and save it after validation.

The docs for profile2_load_by_user is misleading as it indicates that there will always be a profile returned, but looking through the source code I can see a return value of FALSE.

If there is a profile then return value is either a single profile or an array of profiles, so you must test $data for 3 things: false, object, or array of objects.

Comment: So should I do something like if (isseet($profile first and if it returns false I would just assume that all fields are empty?

Comment: I will use empty($profile). If it returns true the user does not yet have a profile, which is similar to you testing if a single or all fields are empty.